# Xcode: No Matching Provisoining Profiles Found

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am on Xcode 7.3, OSX El Capitan 10.11.4.

My work decided to move the dev team from one shared Apple developer account to a shared team account under which we all have individual developer profiles.

Since the migration, I have had an unholy hell of a time getting XCode's provisioning profiles correct.  I have tried deleting all of them, resetting them, reinstalling XCode, transferring my old certificate/key pair, etc.  I have been through the gamut of answers here on SO with little success. I don't have an expired Apple certificate in my keychain, and I don't appear to be missing any private keys.

In my local keychain, I can see all of the certificate/private key pairs it requires.  However, when I try to build it tells me "No code signing identities found" which match the team ID "Your Company Inc ABC123123". However, when I navigate to my build settings I can clearly see provisioning/distribution profiles matching the same ID (ABC123123), but with the old name of the account.  If I use this profile, or rename it to match the current team name Xcode expects, it is still unable to find the code signing identities.

If I then click the cruelly named 'Fix Issue' button and then reset my certificate, it yields another headscratching error:

An App ID with Identifier 'com.myappname.mycompanyname' is not available.  Please enter a different string.

I would just nuke everything in the member center and start fresh, but we have other devs who are able to build using the current distribution/provisioning profiles as well as clients with deployed apps.

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated as I am losing my mind.

Comment: Try this: Go to Xcode preferences, account, select your company's dev account, tap View Details, and then tap Download All. And then rebuild.

Comment: I've already tried this unfortunately :(  Thanks though!

Comment: Delete everything from ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/ ?

Comment: I'm afraid I've tried this as well.

Comment: I would guess that the application ID is still under the old developer account, not the new team account.  Can you log into the team account on the developer site and verify that you've created the applicatiion ID there?